# How to use Cassandra sstableupgrade tool?

Tags: cassandra, upgrade

I'm in the process of migrating Cassandra data from 1.1.3 to 1.2.13. I'm planing to do this migration one node at a time. [Documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/tools/ToolsSSTableupgrade_t.html) says sstableupgrade should be used with following syntax.

```
sstableupgrade [options] <keyspace> <cf> [snapshot]
```

I have 2 questions.

1) Do I have to do this for all column families separately?

2) I have snapshots from 1.1.3 cluster. How should I use this tool to upgrade this snapshots to be compatible with 1.2.10? What should be the value for `[snapshot]` in above syntax?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

Steps I followed. (In each node)

Say I have 1.1.3 distribution extracted in dir A, and data dir is A/data

1) Took snapshots old 1.1.3 node.

2) Extracted 1.2.13 to dir B.

3) Pointed 1.2..13's data folder as A/data

Now Can I start 1.2.13 node before upgrading ss tables to be compatible with 1.2.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "nodetool upgradesstables" to upgrade all the column families and snapshots.

Comment: At which cluster? I have 1.1.3 snapshots. What is the next step? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by migrating? you have two clusters? and you are moving from one cluster to another? I assumed you are upgrading the cluster. In case if you are moving the data? how are you doing that?

Comment: I'm doing an upgrade. I updated the question to answer your question. Please correct me if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes. You can start the service. But before you need to stop the older version. And after successfully starting the new version, you can run the nodetool upgradesstables